# Standing on feet while doing sit-ups

Tags: personal-training, sit-ups

So yesterday my personal trainer stood on my toes while I did sit ups. More than 30 hours has past and my toes are still sore. I’ve ditched the trainer as I didn’t think he was that good anyway and my sore toes is the final straw.

I just wanted to know if standing on someone’s foot is an appropriate way to anchor them down?

Comment: FWIW, my opinion is "no". There are better ways to hold feet (if, indeed, feet need to be held).

Answer (score 2):

#### A trainer should acquire your consent before touching you in any way.

This should be common sense, but apparently it is not. I have done some personal training, and there can be times where touching the athlete, for example to help demonstrate a movement pattern, can be helpful. But I *always* ask the athlete, "may I put my hands on your elbows?" or whatever I am trying to do, and acquire verbal consent from the athlete prior to touching them at all. In your case, standing on the athletes toes is pretty common for providing assistance with sit ups, though I have never had an athlete mention pain, and again, I have always asked the athlete prior to doing so.